# What does 'simple' mean in the following context?

Tags: word-meaning

I met with this question while doing SAT reading,

> But change the conversation to food, and suddenly efficiency doesn’t look so good. Conventional industrial agriculture has become incredibly efficient on a **simple** land to food basis.Thanks to fertilizers,mechanizationandirrigation, each American farmer feeds over 155 people worldwide.

The answer gives 'straightforward' as the best definition,but I still can't wrap my head around it. Actually I feel confused about the whole second sentence. What does it mean?

Comment: "I feel confused about the whole second sentence" isn't helpful unless you say what the confusion is.

Answer (score 2):

It would mean "basic."

"Land to food basis" is comparing how much land is used and how much food is produced on that land. A lot of food grown in a small area = good.

Answer (score 1):

It is an extraneous word that does not modify the thought. It probably is intended as a synonym for "basic," but a basis is basic by definition.

The whole sentence would be a lot clearer expressed as

**Industrial agriculture has become incredibly efficient in terms of food produced versus land used.**

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this by analysing the grammar rather than the vocabulary.

Original:

*Conventional industrial agriculture has become incredibly efficient on a simple land to food basis.*

Explanation:

In English we can have a list of adjectives qualifying a single noun, e.g. "the big red ball"

*land-to-food* is an adjectival phrase that qualifies *basis*.

*simple* is an adjective that qualifies *basis*.

Thus:

*simple land-to-food basis*

(Adj)  (Adj phrase) (noun)